# Problemas al actualizar el código que utiliza la función obsoleta each()

Tags: php

Buen día, estuve revisando un proyecto en php y al probarlo en un servidor local en la versión de php 7.2, obtengo algunos errores: *Message*.

Según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php), la función **each**, esta obsoleta.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar este fragmento de código?

```
  //while ($bar = each($array)) { //Message: The each() function is deprecated.
        foreach ($array as $bar) {
            $array[$bar["key"]] = $this->trata_aspas(trim($rs[$bar["key"]])); //Message: Illegal string offset 'value'
        }
    }
```

**Actualizado**: puede ayudarme con esto?

```
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($bar["value"] != "") {
            if (is_numeric($bar["value"])) {
                $sql .= " AND " . $bar["key"] . " = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["conn"], $bar["value"]) . "' ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND " . $this->like($bar["key"], $bar["value"]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Actualizé la respuesta con una breve explicación de la diferencia entre `each` y `foreach` y las correcciones necesarias para el nuevo fragmento que agregaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `each` te permitía declarar una variable `$bar` que contenía 2 propiedades: `$key` (la clave o índice del elemento) y `$val` (el valor del elemento).

Por otro lado, `foreach` nos permite acceder al valor y/o a la clave directamente. `foreach` tiene dos "modos":

```php
foreach($array as $value){
  //Aquí $value contiene el valor de cada elemento
}
```

y

```php
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  //Aquí $key es la clave o índice del elemento
  //Y $value es el valor del elemento
}
```

Entonces en tu código habría que reemplazar `$bar[$key]` por `$key`. Quedaría así:

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = $this->trata_aspas(trim($rs[$key]));
}
```

En el código que comentaste también habría que reemplazar `$bar["value"]` por `$value`. Quedaría así:

```php
if ($value != "") {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        $sql .= " AND " . $key . " = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["conn"], $value) . "' ";
    } else {
        $sql .= " AND " . $this->like($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buen día @Kal, si tienes una nueva pregunta por favor crea una nueva publicación, si es parte de la misma pregunta (Exactamente el mismo tema) por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información ahí.

Comment: Buen día @Fedex7501, ¿Podrías agregar una explicación de la diferencia entre `each` y  `foreach` para que le quede más claro al OP?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato puedo intentarlo